# Should a question with a flaw be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion

Suppose I put up a question which I think contains some flaw. If the question is proved to contain a flaw by others, thus making it unanswerable, should I delete the question, or should I let it stay?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the question has an upvoted answer, the issue is moot: you will not be able to delete it. Generally, you should refrain from deleting questions with a 0-score answer too (unless the answer is also worthless).

For unanswered questions, a guiding principle can be: what will [make The Internet a better place](http://stackexchange.com/):  the existence of your question with a comment  indicating it is unanswerable, or its absence? There is a spectrum between "a natural, naive question with an insightful comment" and "esoteric question that will be a dead-end in search results for users looking for something else". So, consider how natural the question is, and in what sense it is "unanswerable". At the end of the day, it's your call.

Comment: I think the "insightful comment" should get a bit more emphasis. It's never good to make insightful comments vanish.

Comment: I clicked on your link *make The Internet a better place* expecting to find a FAQ or guide. Why link to StackExchange?

Comment: I *think* he is implying that making the Internet a better place is what Stack Exchange is all about.